# Vision API quota/budget limit and API key security

Tags: google-cloud-vision

I have never used Vision API before but recently I have found it very powerful for a project of mine. However I have two concerns regarding its budget limiting, in order to not get an unexpected bill:

1. Is it possible to set a monthly cost limit? I have been used to Compute Engine which gives me an almost exact cost of the month but this seems not possible here. Since I will be using the API for labelling I have set the label detections requests per minute and per user to a specific amount, also to be sure I have set the global request per minute and per user to the same amount, all the other quotas to 0. If I have understood correctly, setting the max calls quota per minute to 4, for example, should provide a maximum of 178560 calls per month, right? Should this limit my budget? Am I safe?
2. The API will be used as an API key in a mobile app. I have followed the code examples for iOS & Android and I have seen the key is written in the code. Is this safe? For a better security I have restricted the key to iOS/Android apps bundle and to Cloud Vision API only. Would it be a safe enough option?

Thanks everyone for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, it’s possible to set a monthly cost limit. Refer to this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/budgets#create-budget) for more information about creating the budget, setting the budget scope, budget amount and threshold. Yes your understanding is correct by setting the max calls quota per minute to 4, it should provide a maximum of 178560 calls per month. It shouldn’t limit the maximum quotas.
2. API keys that are embedded in the code are not safe and secured.

> Do not embed API keys directly in code. API keys that are embedded in code can be accidentally exposed to the public. For example, you may forget to remove the keys from code that you share. Instead of embedding your API keys in your applications, store them in environment variables or in files outside of your application's source tree.

Refer to this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys#securing_an_api_key) for more information about best practices for securing an API key.

**Edit based on a question in the comment:**

Can the quotas be seen as a hard limit?

- The quotas might be seen as a hard limit only if you don't have any other resources running in your GCP project other than Vision API requests. Refer to this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/capping-api-usage) for more information about capping API usage.
- If you want to set a hard limit and disable billing, configure a Cloud Function to call the Cloud Billing API that disables billing for the project as described in the GCP [doc](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/notify#cap_disable_billing_to_stop_usage).

Note: Use this feature only if you want to stop the spending and might be willing to shutdown all your Google Cloud services and usage when your budget limit is reached.

Comment: Thank you for your precious tips! I have proceeded embedding the key into a ssl secured server. I have checked the budget doc, however I am looking for a hard limit, and the budget feature, if I understand correctly, will simply send an alert. Can the quotas be seen as a hard limit? I.e., setting the request to 4 will never exceed the limit. To be safer I have also implemented nginx rate limiting.

Comment: Hello @reapf, I have updated the answer for your new question. Please take a look.